# Is it natural and correct to say "let's introduce to each other"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Is it natural and correct to say *let's introduce to each other*? For example:

> I am your new teacher so **let's introduce to each other**.

Would it be better to say

> I am your new teacher so **let's ourselves introduce to each other**?

What is the most natural way to say that?

Comment: The **to** is not idiomatic. I would usually say "Let's introduce **ourselves**."

Comment: The ***to each other*** part isn't *necessary*, but it's [perfectly common.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22introduce+ourselves+to+each%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natural.  "Let's introduce ourselves"  is okay.  "... to each other" is rather redundant, but not really wrong.

But I wouldn't feel the need to say anything at all.  It depends a little on the students, and their ages and English abilities and the reason you want them to introduce themselves.  But I'd probably just introduce myself, and then dialogue with the students: "Tell me you name", "Let me know a little bit about why want to improve your English" etc etc.